# How to get input element with puppeteer, when the page load all elements inside frameset tag

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I am trying to get all input element in this website:

http://rwis.mdt.mt.gov/scanweb/swframe.asp?Pageid=SfHistoryTable&Units=English&Groupid=269000&Siteid=269003&Senid=0&DisplayClass=NonJava&SenType=All&CD=7%2F1%2F2020+10%3A41%3A50+AM

Here is element source page looks like.

[image: screenshot]

here is my code:

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");
function run() {
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
      const page = await browser.newPage();
      await page.goto(
        "http://rwis.mdt.mt.gov/scanweb/swframe.asp?Pageid=SfHistoryTable&Units=English&Groupid=269000&Siteid=269003&Senid=0&DisplayClass=NonJava&SenType=All&CD=7%2F1%2F2020+10%3A41%3A50+AM"
      );
      let urls = await page.evaluate(() => {
        let results = [];
        let items = document.querySelectorAll("input").length;
        return items;
      });
      browser.close();
      return resolve(urls);
    } catch (e) {
      return reject(e);
    }
  });
}
run().then(console.log).catch(console.error);
```

Right now my output have 0, when i run `document.querySelectorAll("input").length` in the console, it give me `8` .

It seems like everything is loaded in the frameset  tag, this might be the issue, could anyone have any idea how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 3):

You have to get the frame element, from there you can get the frame itself so you can call evaluate inside that frame:

```js
const elementHandle = await page.$('frame[name=SWContent]');
const frame = await elementHandle.contentFrame();
let urls = await frame.evaluate(() => {
  let results = [];
  let items = document.querySelectorAll("input").length;
  return items;
});
```